# The characters change shape in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have an issue with Matplotlib it read Arabic, not the correct picture will show the result

I will put the code below

This code has a window that imports Excel and from Excel, it read and makes a chart from it

code is working well but the issue with the title

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QComboBox
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Excel File Plotter")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 250)

        self.button = QPushButton("Import Excel File", self)
        self.button.setGeometry(100, 50, 200, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.import_excel_file)

        self.chart_type_combobox = QComboBox(self)
        self.chart_type_combobox.setGeometry(100, 120, 200, 30)
        self.chart_type_combobox.addItems([u"خط الرسم", u"رسم الشريط", u"رسم النقاط", u"رسم الأعمدة", u"رسم الدائرة", u"رسم الخط"])

        self.plot_button = QPushButton("Plot", self)
        self.plot_button.setGeometry(100, 170, 200, 50)
        self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_data)

        self.df = None

    def import_excel_file(self):
        file_dialog = QFileDialog(self)
        file_path, _ = file_dialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Excel File", "", "Excel Files (*.xlsx)")

        if file_path:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            self.df.columns = [arabic_reshaper.reshape(col) for col in self.df.columns]

    def plot_data(self):
        if self.df is None:
            print("Please import an Excel file first.")
            return

        chart_type = self.chart_type_combobox.currentText()

        # Convert row title and chart labels to Unicode strings
        x = [str(col) for col in self.df.columns]
        y = self.df.iloc[0]

        # Set font properties for Arabic text
        font_path = FontProperties(family='Times New Roman').get_file()
        arabic_font = FontProperties(fname=font_path)

        plt.figure()

        if chart_type == u"خط الرسم":
            plt.plot(x, y)
        elif chart_type == u"رسم الشريط":
            plt.bar(x, y)
        elif chart_type == u"رسم النقاط":
            plt.scatter(x, y)
        elif chart_type == u"رسم الأعمدة":
            plt.bar(x, y)
        elif chart_type == u"رسم الدائرة":
            plt.pie(y, labels=x, autopct='%1.1f%%')
        elif chart_type == u"رسم الخط":
            plt.plot(x, y)

        # Reshape and display Arabic labels using arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm
        reshaped_x = [get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(label)) for label in x]
        reshaped_title = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(chart_type))

        plt.xlabel(reshaped_x, fontproperties=arabic_font)
        plt.ylabel(u'القيم', fontproperties=arabic_font)
        plt.title(reshaped_title, fontproperties=arabic_font)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

code is working well but the issue is with the title only if you can look at how I can read Arabic correctly or if you know another lab than matplotlib

Comment: There are two approaches:

(1) hack the strings using python bidi and arabic_reshaper packages. The bidi package converts a logical string to a visual layout string. the arabic_reshaper changes the codepoints, replacing the Unicode arabic codepoints for the presentation forms or (2) Use mplcairo as the backend for matplotlib. mplcairo uses libraqm, which in turn uses fribidi or sheen for bidirectional support and Harfbuzz for opentype font rendering.